# Compile C on Linux - missing procinfo.h

Tags: c, linux, redhat, aix

Trying to build source code brought from IBM AIX OS to Linux RedHat 7 OS.

There is a header file, procinfo.h., that is available via IBM AIX that I need to Linux RedHat. The IBM AIX info: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/g_bostechref/getprocs.html . Does anyone know the equivallent Linux C library for reading the /proc temp directory. I am looking for the same functions calls as IBM AIX procinfo.h and proc.h on a Linux box.

Comment: Here's an interesting thread on the topic: [`procinfo.h` is not with the kernel source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/procinfo-h-is-not-with-the-kernel-source%5Blinux-2-6-18-238-e15-4175558366/). What kernel version are you using?

Comment: 3.10.0-1062.e17.x86_64

Comment: This link may also be useful: [LINUX KERNEL DEVELOPMENT – CREATING A PROC FILE AND INTERFACING WITH USER SPACE](https://devarea.com/linux-kernel-development-creating-a-proc-file-and-interfacing-with-user-space/#.XvT2dUVKgVB).